# How to add 1 hour to a combined date and time

Tags: awk

I have a comma-separated input file with 7 columns where:

- column 3 is the date in format `yyyymmdd`
- column 4 is the time in the format `HHMMSS`.

I would like to update these two columns by adding **one hour** to the combined date-time format. This implies:

- If `HH` < 23, only update the fourth column
- If `HH` >= 23, update both columns as we move to the next day.

Below you find one of my attempts, with input and expected output.

**comment:** as was pointed out in the comments below, I do not have access to GNU awk. So my attempt is failing as I made use of the time-functions `strftime`

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }                 
     {
        if($4<230000)                    
            $4=sprintf("%06d",$4+10000)
        else
           {
             $4=sprintf("%06d",$4-230000)
             $3+=86400  
            }
            print                                             
      }' Test.txt > A.txt
```

**Sample Data:**

```
1039,1018,20180915,000000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,010000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,020000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,030000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,240000,0,0,A
```

**expected output:**

```
1039,1018,20180915,010000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,020000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,030000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,040000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180916,010000,0,0,A
```

Comment: Can you clarify what `$4` is, and what your code should be doing with it? Is it a *time of day*, or a *duration*? And are timezones or daylight savings a concern?

Comment: Please concider to use the [GNU awk time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions) and avoid the shell call to `date`. Use `mktime` to convert everything to seconds. Perform your operations as requested (add 86400 seconds to add a day) and convert the seconds back to a day with `strftime`.

Comment: Also, `strftime` expects seconds and not a dateformat `YYYYMMDD` so you will receive the wrong date/time.

Comment: @ghoti $4 is time, if $4 is less than 230000(hrs) so need to add one hrs, else change the date of $3 to next day and update the $4 value i.e. minus 230000

Comment: @Sameer, could you please give information about `$3` (does it represent `YYYYMMDD`), `$4` (does it represent `hhmmss`), and does the `output` section represent the expected output and if so, how do you want to obtain this. The reason I ask this is that hte current code adds various `print` statements that I do not see in you output.

Comment: @kvantour for strftime i am getting error like Function is not define. and i dont know how to use GNU awk time function.

Comment: @kvantour $3 represent YYYYMMDD only no time stamp and $4 is hhmmss (010000)

Comment: @kvantour for >which awk
/usr/bin/awk
and >awk --version
awk: Not a recognized flag: -

Comment: @Sameer you are not working with GNU awk and should switch to POSIX (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)

Comment: @kvantour thanks, how i achieve my output and could u plz help me on same. i am new on unix side and tried lot but not get output.

Comment: @Sameer, apart from what kvantour said, add O.S details too where you are trying to write the command.

Comment: @kvantour post was updated.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i conected client machine, don't know much about OS

Comment: @kvantour, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I didn't read close enough your situation. As some have helpfully pointed out, this is an alternative solution using GNU awk.

```
  #!/usr/bin/awk -f

    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    {
        if($4<230000)
            $4=sprintf("%06d",$4+10000)
        else
           {
             $4=sprintf("%06d",$4-230000)
             year=substr($3, 1,4)
             month=substr($3, 5,2)
             day=substr($3, 7,2)
             dstr=year " " month " " day " 00 00 00"
             dstamp=mktime(dstr)
             dstamp+=86400
             $3=strftime("%Y%m%d",dstamp)
            }
            print
     }
```

$ ./script.awk Test.txt

```
1039,1018,20180915,010000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,020000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,030000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180915,040000,0,0,A
1039,1018,20180916,010000,0,0,A
```

Comment: This makes use of `mktime` and hence is GNU awk, the OP does not have access to GNU tools. Otherwise a good solution!

Comment: function `mktime` is not available in POSIX `awk` either.

Answer (score 3):

Use system command to add 1 day to the column 3

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    if($4<230000)
        $4=sprintf("%06d",$4+10000)
    else {
         $4=sprintf("%06d",$4-230000)
         date="$( date -d '19500101')";
         #print strftime("%Y%m%d",$3);
         #$3+=86400


         # # GNU date
         # $3 = strftime("%Y%m%d", (24*3600)+mktime(substr($3,1,4)" "substr($3,5,2)" "substr($3,7)" 00 00 00"))

         # BSD date
         $3=((sprintf("date -j -v+1d -f \"%%Y%%m%%d\" %s \"+%%Y%%m%%d\"", $3) | getline line) > 0 ? line: "INVALID DATE" )
    }
    print
 }' Test.txt
```

The `date` command is GNU `date`. see [GNU Coreutils: date invocation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html)

If you run this script on macOS, make sure you have `coreutils` installed.  If not, using `brew` to install it.

```
brew install coreutils
```

---

Update

Don't use `date` command anymore. Combine @ExpertNoob1's answer.

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    if($4<230000)
        $4=sprintf("%06d",$4+10000)
    else {
         $4=sprintf("%06d",$4-230000)
         date="$( date -d '19500101')";
         #print strftime("%Y%m%d",$3);
         #$3+=86400
         $3 = strftime("%Y%m%d", (24*3600)+mktime(substr($3,1,4)" "substr($3,5,2)" "substr($3,7)" 00 00 00"))
    }
    print
 }' Test.txt
```

Comment: it given wrong result, if i have date like 20180930 this, it returning 20180931 but i want 20181001

Comment: no problem, i am getting date: Not a recognized flag: -
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"] this error

Comment: @Sameer Which version of `date` command are you using? Can you run `date --version` to confirm? We should see the first line like `date (GNU coreutils)`

Comment: date -u
Mon Sep 17 14:39:48 GMT 2018
date --version is not working date --version
date: Not a recognized flag: -
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]

Comment: This is the problem, it seems that the `date` command doesn't come from GNU or BSD. Can you show `type -a date`, and `/bin/date --version`

Comment: ..>type -a date
ksh: whence: 0403-010 A specified flag is not valid for this command.

Comment: Oh, it's ksh. Run the command `whence -a date`, and the command `uname -a`

Comment: whence -a date
ksh: whence: 0403-010 A specified flag is not valid for this command.

Comment: I'm curious about the OS your client is using. Can you show the result of command `uname`?

Comment: The OP is running on a SUN OS, so he has no access to the default gnu toolkit. One should assume that there is no existence of `gdate` or allike.

Comment: I do not understand why this is concidered to be the valid solution is it cannot be. It makes use of gnu awk and gnu core-utils.

Comment: @kvantour Agree.

Answer (score 2):

Without GNU awk extensions available, I *think* this may be what you're really after.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  OFS=FS=","
  split("31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31", days, " ")
}

{
  # Add one hour to the current time
  $4=sprintf("%06d", $4 + 10000 )

  # Is this a leap year?
  year=substr($3,1,4)
  if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
    days[2]=29
  } else {
    days[2]=28
  }
}

# too many hours
$4 >= 240000 {
  $3=$3 + int($4/240000)           # add days for sets of 24 hours
  $4=sprintf("%06d", $4 % 24000 )  # reduce time to < 24 hours

  # too many days
  if (substr($3,7,2) > days[substr($3,5,2)+0]) {
    $3=sprintf( "%04d%02d%02d", substr($3,1,4), substr($3,5,2)+1, substr($3,7,2)-days[substr($3,5,2)+0] )

    # too many months
    if (substr($3,5,2) > 12) {
      $3=sprintf( "%04d%02d%02d", substr($3,1,4)+1, substr($3,5,2)-12, substr($3,7,2) )
    }
  }
}

# print the line
1
```

This steps through significant overages from smallest unit to largest. It obviously could be compacted a little; things are spread out for commenting.

- If we have too many hours, we add them as days to the "day" part of the date.
- If we have too many days for the current month, we increment the month.
- If we have too many months for a year, we increment the year.

Seems to work on your data. as well as dates+times around a few leap years. I haven't tested it further.

Note that it does not take into account DST transitions or leap seconds.

Comment: I like your assumption that this script will still run in the year 2100.

Comment: @kvantour, you never know, eh? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$3 = strftime("%Y%m%d", (24*3600)+mktime(substr($3,1,4)" "substr($3,5,2)" "substr($3,7)" 00 00 00"))
```